# SSL refused by Chrome but passes SSL test

Tags: nginx, ssl

When I request my website from Google Chrome, I receive a CERT_INVALID error, but [when I test it using Qualys SSL test, it passes all tests and receives a A+](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=stuffwithinstuff.com). In addition to this, SSL seems to be working with every other browser.

The SSL Cert being used is a domain validated certificate from PositiveSSL.

The order in which I packaged the CA certs is:

1. domain_cert.pem
2. COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.pem
3. COMODORSAAddTrustCA.pem
4. AddTrustExternalCARoot.pem

So that the command used to package is the following:

> cat domain_cert.pem COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.pem COMODORSAAddTrustCA.pem AddTrustExternalCARoot.pem > ssl-bundle.crt

Which should be correct, but I get a browser error as in the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not just you?  I don't get a cert error in Chrome when I access your [empty?] site.

[image]

Comment: That's really strange. I get this: http://i.imgur.com/rvoB1a2.png  

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Saikyr Like Ad7six said in his comment on your question, it's probably some locally cached something.  Try from a different computer and see what you see.

Comment: Definitely works my phone - I'll have to try clear my chrome cache then. Really weird though, the displayed cert in the error matches the one I set in nginx so I don't see where cache comes in.

Comment: @Saikyr Chrome version? You're in "it's just my browser" territory atm.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. On version 40, OSX. Added COMODO certs to keychain, doesn't seem to be helping. Doesn't seem to be a clear ssl cache option either, posts using the change proxy method don't account for OSX; it just opens network preferences which doesn't have anything related to SSL or certs.